# Definition of nonstandard $\omega$

Tags: logic, set-theory

I would like to know what is THE definition of a "nonstandard $\omega$", or to be exact of "the model $M$ (of set-theory) has a nonstandard $\omega$" (if there is one agreed definition). Is it one of the following statements?

1. $\omega^M$ is ill-founded.
2. There is $x\in M$ such that  $M\vDash x\in \omega$ and for every $n\in \omega$, $M\vDash \mathbf{n}<x$ (where $\mathbf{n}$ is the term $1+\dots+1$ $n$ times).
3. $\omega^M\ne\omega$.
4. $\omega^M$ is not order isomorphic to $\omega$. [added following Andres's comment]

I'm quite sure 1 and 2 are equivalent, and I think that also 3. If that is so, can I give either one as the definition?

Comment: That $M$ has a non-standard $\omega$ means that $\omega^M$ is not order-isomorphic to $\omega$. This is really what you should write in 3 rather than simply set-theoretic inequality. This is indeed equivalent to 1 and 2.

Comment: And this is the "standard" definition? (pun intended)
Should I edit the question?

Comment: Yes, that is the standard definition. In the new version you have, 3 is simply not equivalent to any of the other statements. Set-theoretic equality is too strong a requirement. For instance, start with your favorite model $(M,\in_M)$ of set theory and now consider $(M',\in')$, where $M'=\{(a,0)\mid a\in M\}$ and $(a,0)\in'(b,0)$ iff $a\in_M b$. Clearly, $M$ and $M'$ are the same thing, that they are different *as sets* is just noise. In particular, if $\omega^M$ is standard, then $\omega^{M'}$ is standard as well, although by design $\omega\ne\omega^{M'}$.

Comment: You can always collapse whatever part of $M$ is well founded to be transitive. Under this assumption 3 joins the equivalence. (Also, didn't we cover this four years ago? Although that was in the context of PA...)

Comment: yes, I see. I'm leaving 3 as it is to emphasize these issues for anyone who might also be looking at this question. @Andrés Would you like to turn this into an answer?

Comment: @Asaf do you mean in Logic 2? I guess we talked about the fact that there are nonstandard models of PA but I don't recall we dwelled on it, and I'm quite sure we didn't discuss it in the set-theoretic context. I don't know if there was an official definition, but I guess we talked more in terms of 2. above, since it is the one following directly from Compactness. Also the notion of "the real $\mathbb{N}$" was more an intuitive one, rather than one based on the ambient set-theoretic universe.

Comment: Yeah, I went over the exercises from that year, and it was quite haphazard. I guess in later years with Itay we talked in more details about non-standard models. Also, the notion of "the real $\Bbb N$" was based on an ambient set-theoretic universe, I just didn't say that because whenever I mentioned set theory everyone freaked out (and you, specifically, told me that most people in the class have no idea what ZFC even means).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix a model $M$ of a theory for which it makes sense to talk about $\omega$ ($M$ does not need to be a model of set theory, it could even be simply an ordered set with a minimum in which every element has an immediate successor and every element other than the minimum has an immediate predecessor; in this case we could identify $\omega^M$ with $M$ itself).

We say that $\omega^M$ is non-standard if and only if (by definition) $\omega^M$ is not order-isomorphic to $\omega$.

By induction (in the ambient theory) there is a unique order embedding from (true) $\omega$ onto a unique initial segment of $\omega^M$. That $\omega^M$ is non-standard thus means precisely that this embedding is not surjective. If $k$ is an element of $\omega^M$ not in its range, then its immediate predecessor is also not in the range, and it follows that $\omega^M$ is ill-founded. (Conversely, if $\omega^M$ is ill-founded, obviously it is not order isomorphic to $\omega$.)

Identifying the elements of the range with their preimages, this gives us your condition 2 as well (without needing to have a $+$ operation in the structure; naturally, if your $M$ is such that we can discuss the $+$ of $\omega^M$ and expect it to satisfy basic first-order properties of the $+$ of true $\omega$, then the image of any $n\in\omega$ under the unique embedding we are discussing is precisely the ${\mathbf n}$ of your formulation of condition 2).

On the other hand, condition 3 (that $\omega^M\ne\omega$) is too strong a requirement, since usually we only care about structures up to isomorphism. It is true, as Asaf pointed out in a comment, that in some (but definitely not all) situations we may want to identify the well-founded part of a model with its transitive collapse (meaning, given $M$ we effectively replace it with an isomorphic $M'$ obtained by replacing the well-founded part of $M$ as indicated, and then proceed to discuss $M'$ exclusively rather than $M$). If this is the case, then yes, of course condition 3 is also equivalent to the other conditions.

But note that even in the context of set theory, even when considering well-founded models, there are natural circumstances when we want to discuss models that are not transitive. For example, it is common in infinitary combinatorics to argue about elementary substructures $M$ of (some initial segment of) the universe. These structures are automatically well-founded, but you do not want to replace them with their transitive counterparts. (It is also true, however, than in this specific example $\omega^M=\omega$, but I hope the point is clear.)